# LibGDX - Comparing Sprites in the Fragment Shader

Tags: libgdx, shader, textures, sprite

I am working on a LibGDX project, and I would like to be able to modify things like the color and alpha of a sprite, specifically on any part that overlaps the previously placed one.  From what I can tell, this would only be possible by somehow comparing the two inside of the fragment shader and then modifying the individual fragments as necessary in there.

My problem at the moment is that I am having trouble figuring out how to even get the data from both sprites into the fragment shader to do these comparisons.  Since any sprites that need to be doing this will always be using the same texture as each other, do I only need to bring in the coordinate data for the sprite I am comparing to, since the other one loaded the "texture"?

The entire process is a bit baffling to me as I've never had to do anything similar before, so any ideas on what to attempt is appreciated.  At this point I can control the individual sprites just fine through the fragment shader, it's just comparing two separately placed sprites from within the fragment shader to see where they are overlapping that is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off computing the intersection of your two sprites in your Java code, and then rendering the resulting overlap area with a relatively basic shader.  (Just draw it on top of the vanilla rendering of the sprite.)

Comment: I wasn't aware it was possible to do very specific pixel checking of that sort in Java itself.  What exactly would I look up to research this possibility?  It sounds like something that would be very taxing when done nearly constantly, as I need it to.  I am fairly certain the shader route I've been going is viable as I was able to partially fake the effect by creating a fake copy of the texture within the shader, offset the texture coordinates, and use that for the comparison. It is clearly doing what I need it to, but obviously it isn't an actual solution beyond simple, controllable tests.